# Best way to handle User object changes with BLOC

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am getting into BLOC and I am failing to see the best way to make it possible for my User object to be changed by events coming from multiple BLOCs.

Example - lets say I am building a social media app

AuthBloc contains Sign up / Sign in events and on success emits state with User object which contains some basic data and list of posts.

Home screen reads that state and shows data from the User object.

Problem:

As part of different BLOC - lets say PostBloc - there are events related to CRUD actions for user's posts.

Each of these events changes User object's "posts" List and therefor it returns a new User object with updated list of posts.

This creates a problem because state of User returned from AuthBloc is old and no longer relevant because PostBloc's state returns User with same data as AuthBloc + new posts list.

What is best approach here? I tried looking up different examples as well as official Bloc examples but none of them seem to be very complete - they all like cover basic authentication flow but never actually proceed further with how to manage the user state afterwards.

Ideally I would like to make it so each Bloc can update user object's properties but the I am failing to see approach for this if we consider that everything should cause Bloc event and event should emit new State.

Answer (score 0):

on BLOC there are 2 states.

[https://bloclibrary.dev/#/blocnamingconventions:~:text=%E2%9C%85-,Good,-sealed%20class%20CounterEvent](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/blocnamingconventions:%7E:text=%E2%9C%85-,Good,-sealed%20class%20CounterEvent)

i think you should update the Users data on Userbloc state too.
i recommend you to use the SingleClass state

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article, hope it would help you:

[The Observer Pattern: Facilitating Bloc Dependency Management in Dart](https://hamed-rezaee.medium.com/the-observer-pattern-facilitating-bloc-dependency-management-in-dart-db69c19ae541)

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree with your statement that the docs are not very complete. You have a simple matter of bloc to bloc communication, which are addressed very specifically in the architecture section of [bloclibary.dev](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture)

## From the docs:

> `Because blocs expose streams, it may be tempting to make a bloc which listens to another bloc. You should not do this. There are better alternatives than resorting to the code below:`

```
  final OtherBloc otherBloc;
  late final StreamSubscription otherBlocSubscription;

  BadBloc(this.otherBloc) {
    // No matter how much you are tempted to do this, you should not do this!
    // Keep reading for better alternatives!
    otherBlocSubscription = otherBloc.stream.listen((state) {
      add(MyEvent());
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    otherBlocSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

> `While the code above is error free (and even cleans up after itself), it has a bigger problem: it creates a dependency between two blocs.`

> `Generally, sibling dependencies between two entities in the same architectural layer should be avoided at all costs, as it creates tight-coupling which is hard to maintain. Since blocs reside in the business logic architectural layer, no bloc should know about any other bloc.`

> `Application Architecture Layers`

> `A bloc should only receive information through events and from injected repositories (i.e., repositories given to the bloc in its constructor).`

> `If you're in a situation where a bloc needs to respond to another bloc, you have two other options. You can push the problem up a layer (into the presentation layer), or down a layer (into the domain layer).`

> `Connecting Blocs through Presentation You can use a BlocListener to listen to one bloc and add an event to another bloc whenever the first bloc changes.`

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<FirstBloc, FirstState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // When the first bloc's state changes, this will be called.
        //
        // Now we can add an event to the second bloc without it having
        // to know about the first bloc.
        BlocProvider.of<SecondBloc>(context).add(SecondEvent());
      },
      child: TextButton(
        child: const Text('Hello'),
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<FirstBloc>(context).add(FirstEvent());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> `The code above prevents SecondBloc from needing to know about FirstBloc, encouraging loose-coupling. The flutter_weather application uses this technique to change the app's theme based on the weather information that is received.`

So in your case, its a simple matter of creating a `BlocListener<PostBloc>` widget, and in the `listener` callback, fire an event from the `AuthBloc` that takes in a list of `Posts` via the event, and updates the `User` object with the updated list. That way, after any CRUD operation of the `PostBloc`, the `User` object is automatically updated.

I do not recommend the observer pattern suggested one of the other answers because a) It goes against the recommended pattern of the creator of the library, and b) Its just more complex than it needs to be.